# Generar un Login con SQL Server y PHP

Tags: php, html, sql-server

Estoy tratando de realizar la validación de mi formulario de inicio de sesión en mi pagina con `php`, y tengo que tomar los valores  que están en mi base de datos de `SQL Server` el código de mi formulario es el siguiente:

```html
<form name="login" action="log_action.php" method="post">
    IdEquip: <input class="form" type="text" name="id-equipaje"><br />
    IdPas: <input class="form" type="text" name="id-pasajero"><br />
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

Y mi archivo `php` es el siguiente:

```html
<?php
session_start();

require_once 'conexionSQL.php';

$EquipajeId = $_POST['id-equipaje'];
$Pasajero  = $_POST['id-pasajero'];

$tsql = "SELECT * FROM Id_Equipaje WHERE Id_Equipaje='$EquipajeId' AND Id_Pasajero='$Pasajero'";
$result = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql, $params, array( "Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET ));

$num = sqlsrv_num_rows($result);
if($num==1){
    header('Location: index.php');
    $_SESSION['valid_user'] = true;
    $_SESSION['EmployeeId'] = $EquipajeId;
    die();}
else
    echo"error consulta";
    die();      
?>
```

Mi problema es que cuando ingreso los datos en el formulario, me manda a otra pagina y me aparece todo el código que tengo en mi archivo `php`
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Hola @Adriana veo que estás abriendo los archivos directamente desde donde están ubicados, lo que debes hacer es encender tu servidor local por ejemplo xampp: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego de haber encendido debes escribir en el navegador:

```
localhost/NombreDeTuCarpeta
```

En tu caso sería:

```
localhost/conexion
```

Y recién funcionará tu código de php ya que necesita un servidor para poder interpretar el código.
Espero haberte ayudado. 
Imagen: Extraída de internet

Comment: En este caso con apache sería más que suficiente, pues el servidor de base de datos que ocupa es SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

la url deberia aparecerte de la siguiente manera `http://localhost/.../conexion/log_action.php` sin embargo a ti te abre asi: `c/xampp/htdocs/conexion/log_action.php` lo que significa  que tu  codigo no esta mal sino que apache no esta ejecutando tus scripts php, esto se puede deber a una mala instalacion de xampp